# IF & Else condition in C# with MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image: MySql Workbench]When i am writing if else condition for selecting table based on condition on new query editor window of MySQL Workbench then its giving me error

Here (1=1) is some condition

```
IF (1=1) then 
select 1;
ELSE 
select 2;
END IF;

IF (1=1) then 
select 1;
ELSE 
select 2;
END IF;
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (1=1) then  select 1' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your code in a stored procedure. Use the context menu in the schema tree to create a new procedure and open an editor for it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: In MSSQL this code is working fine.. why in MySql we need to write this code in proc

Comment: I don't know the MSSQL syntax, but in MySQL the code you want to execute is only allowed in a stored routine. That's a syntax requirement. It's a socalled *flow control statement* (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html).

Answer (score 0):

The `IF()` in MySQL is a function. So you could try something like this instead:

```sql
SELECT IF(1=1,1,2)
```

If there are more conditions, you would nest them as:

```sql
SELECT
  IF(1=1,1,
    IF(2=2,2,3)
  )
```

Comment: My scenario is I need to select different different table based on condition.. if var a=b then I need to select another table and need to perform diff action

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 1 WHERE (1=1)
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 WHERE NOT (1=1)
```

But the number (and type) of the columns should be the same for both queries (or, in other words, the 'SELECT 1' and 'SELECT 2' should have the same number of columns and datatypes)

Comment: Please update your question that you need to select from two different tables AND that is mandatory to use IF/ELSE (because this is homework?)